# URL authorization. Check protect page on the login page

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I have the secure page.
ASP.NET redirect me to the login page after non-authorized access to the secure page

How do I know the secure page name on the login page?

Comment: Use the normal pattern. Append the 'return url' on the query string.

Comment: @leppie. How I Can add page name to the query string? Pages are protected on the web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Forms Authentication, you can use the [FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx) method, this will automagically take you back to the original page requested.

Comment: I don't want redirect to the original page. I should know original page name on the login page for the internal logic.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. You can get the original request URL from Forms with the FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl method, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.getredirecturl.aspx